# Why is my tf_gradients returning None?

Tags: tensorflow

```
# Defining the tf ops
prob_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2))
log_placeholder = tf.log(prob_placeholder)
grads_placeholder = tf.gradients(ys=tf.log(prob_placeholder), xs=model.weights)


# t is some index into the holders (which are lists)
# s is some state || p_a is some list of [p_1, 1 - p_1] || a_ is either 0 or 1 ||  r is 1

prob_ = tf_sess.run(prob_placeholder, {prob_placeholder: p_a})
log_ = tf_sess.run(log_placeholder, {prob_placeholder: prob_})
print(prob_, log_)
grads_ = tf_sess.run(grads_placeholder, {prob_placeholder: prob_})
```

Basically I'm not sure why it's returning None.

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>
```

I've tried adding print statements and I can see prob_ and log_ come out just fine but I'm not sure what's happening in tf.gradients that is causing the issue above.

model.weights are basically the weights of the model that I'm using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`prob_placeholder` does not have any explicit dependence on `model.weights`, i.e. it is not functionally dependent on `model.weights` the way you have defined them.

Hence, though technically the gradient should be zero, it is computed as `None` due to [technical reasons in TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783).

Comment: Awesome! So would one method be to make it so that model.output is prob_placeholder? That way prob_placeholder is indirectly related to model.weights?

Comment: @user162264 The usual way is to keep the output labels in a `tf.placeholder` and then compute a loss function which takes the true labels and the output of the NN and computes a value. Then one can calculate the gradient of the loss w.r.t. the model variables.